# NSMutablearray mutated while being enumerated Can you help me in which case this exception occurs in my code

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is an implementation section of a class named "Model". Here I recursively call call the setDictionary method upto 3 layers, which raises an exception (NSMutablearray mutated while being enumerated) this exception can be avoided if I use **for** loop istead of **forin**, I would like to understand how this error occurs...Can any one help...Please dont reply with some links that point to some definition, I already read lots of documentation and I dont understand how the exception is raised in this situation.

```
@implementation Model
@synthesize arraySubOptions,boolHasSub;

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        boolHasSub = NO;
        arraySubOptions = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict{
    boolHasSub = [[[dict objectForKey:@"key_has_sub"] nullCheck:[NSString class]] boolValue];

    if (boolHasSub) {
        NSArray * arrayDict = (NSArray*)[self loadDataFromDB];

        if(arrayDict && (arrayDict.count>0) ){
            for (NSDictionary * dict in arrayDict) {
                Model * objOption = [Model new];
                [objOption setDictionary:dict];
                [arraySubOptions addObject:objOption]; /*This is the line that raises the exception. It raised  */
            }
        }

    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Show your `loadDataFromDB` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[self loadDataFromDB]` returns an array which gets deallocated when the method call ends, since the object was created inside the method. So copying the returned array did the trick.

```
[[self loadDataFromDB] copy]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method

```
[self loadDataFromDB]
```

should be altering your arrayDict, so, when you reach

```
[objOption setDictionary:dict];
```

is entering twice in that function, modifying your arrayDict and launching this exception.

Doing it with 'for' instead of 'foreach' works because you set the limits of your loop and it doesn't reach any exception if your limit isn't out of bounds. (i > arrayDict.count)

Comment: I don't see that's the answer sorry....arrayDict is supposed to change very time that method is called....and when I comment the [arraySubOptions addObject:objOption] the exception does not occur...

Comment: As @kreiri said, please, post your loadDataFromDB code

Comment: I don't have that right now, assume that it returns an NSArray of count 2